How do I go about determining the tension in the anchor rope
an impact force of 100 kN is acting on the top of the column and an anchor rope is attached. an energy dissipator is attached to the anchor rope in the second case. how do I determine the tension in the anchor rope

you didn't learn about static force diagrams? and how to deal with a turning moment in them?

the issue is the second part how do i incorporate the energy dissipator in the analysis

Then you might want to mention that you already solved the non-dissipator part already.

Show what you have done / considered so far.

how do i attach a photo in comments

You can probably add a photo to your original post. The energy dissipator will stretch and change the geometry of the setup a bit which will change the tension in the anchor rope. So you can either write an equation for that, or solve it iteratively.

@Apuuli256 you can add or replace photos in your post.

Energy dissipater is essentially a spring?

yes its a spring
